# Ruby: reverse, mutating list

Tags: ruby, reverse

I'm trying to write a method, which reverses a list, but not using .reverse.
Here is my code:

```
def reverse(list)

  a = list.length

  while a >= 0
    list << list[a]
    a = a - 1
  end
  list
end

print reverse([1,2,3])
```

My expected result isn't [3,2,1] but [1, 2, 3, nil, 3, 2, 1]

Do you have any advice how to not repeat the original list once again, but only mutate it?

Comment: I've updated my answer, see for a more Rubyish approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This *mutates* the original array as requested. `nil` is eliminated by being aware that the last element of the list is at `list[list.length-1]`.

```
def reverse(list)
  a = list.length-1
  while a >= 0
    list << list[a]
    list.delete_at(a)
    a = a - 1
  end
  list
end

p reverse([1, 2, 3]) #=> [3, 2, 1]
```

A more Ruby way could be as follows:

```
arr.sort_by!.with_index { |_,i| -i }
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand the list is to be reversed in place (mutated). Below are two ways to do that.

If the list is not to be mutated, simply operate on a copy:

```
def non_mutating_reverse(list)
  reverse(list.dup)
end
```

**#1**

Use *parallel assignment* (sometimes called *multiple assignment*).

```
def reverse(list)
  (list.size/2).times { |i| list[i], list[-1-i] = list[-1-i], list[i] }
  list
end

list = [1,2,3]
reverse list     #=> [3, 2, 1] 
list             #=> [3, 2, 1]
```

Notice that when the size of the list is odd (as in this example), the middle element is not moved.

**#2**

```
def reverse(list)
  list.replace(list.size.times.with_object([]) { |i,a| a.unshift(list[i]) })
end

list = [1,2,3]
reverse list     #=> [3, 2, 1] 
list             #=> [3, 2, 1]
```